# The MarkLogic Data Hub Research Framework (Pharma R&D) uses the Quickstart GUI, but can it work with Data Hub Central?

Tags: marklogic

I would like to use the MarkLogic Data Hub Framework and Research Hub Example (which was apparently developed using Data Hub 5.1/2) with the latest version of the data hub and Data Hub Central to create and map entities, but the Framework only works with QuickStart.

It also seems that the Framework required the manual creation of TDEs for mapping entities, but DHC seems to do that automagically. Perhaps the MarkLogic Data Hub Framework and Research Hub Example has become obsolete along with QuickStart.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the commit log](https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-research-hub-framework/branches/all) research hub has not been touched by anyone in 2 years.

It should be possible to run the latest version of Research Hub on the old DHF and [then follow the DHF upgrade procedure](https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.7/upgrade.html) to get Research Hub to run on the latest DHF.

You may be best off sharing your interest with your MarkLogic contact(s) and seeing if you can get official support for the effort.